# Social accounts VS site account

Tags: php, social-networking

In my site, I have a table users and there are various columns such as money, ratio, and other things. I wonder how can I attach those columns to the social accounts (Google, Facebook, Twitter etc..). Maybe when the user logs in with Google for example, I can register him on my site and use my own authentication system, and the next time he logs in, he will be logged in as if he were logging in directly to my site... Just a thought. So how can I achieve the unification?

Comment: no, its not the same, i ask how to attach my table columns to the account, and the answers there is not so clear

Comment: You don't attach anything to those accounts -you use `OAuth` to log the user into the account of choice (i.e. you'll need to add a field or two to **your tables** to clarify their account of choice) and then you **do in fact have a user record in your database for them** it just leverages the account of choice for login.